# Number of vectors so that no two subset sums are equal

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle, additive-combinatorics, sumset

Consider all $10$-tuple vectors each element of which is either $1$ or $0$. It is very easy to select a set $v_1,\dots,v_{10}= S$ of $10$ such vectors so that no two distinct subsets of vectors $S_1 \subset S$ and $S_2 \subset S$  have the same sum. Here $\sum_{v \in S_i} v$ assumes simple element-wise addition over $\mathbb{R}$.  For example, if we take the vectors that are the columns of the identity matrix as $S$ this will do.

What is the maximum number of vectors one can choose that have this property?  Is there a counting argument that solves this?

---

A small clarification. The sum of two vectors in this problem is another vector.

---

**Current records:**

- Lower bound: $19$. First given by Brendan McKay over at MO.
- Upper bound: $30$. First given by Brendan McKay over at MO.

---

Cross-posted to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/157634/number-of-vectors-so-that-no-two-subset-sums-are-equal

Comment: If you have more than 10 vectors, then they are linearly dependent, and you can use the dependence relation to get two equal subset sums.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I don't think that is right.  Linear dependence allows you to multiply the vectors by coefficients where in this problem the only multiplicative coefficients are $0$ or $1$.

Comment: I thought by "(multi) subsets" you meant repetitions are allowed --- if not, then I don't understand what the word "multi" is doing there.

Comment: I think you can take the 10 vectors with 9 ones each, and 8 of the vectors with a single one, making 18. Maybe there's a way to do better.

Comment: @GerryMyerson By multi-subset I just mean, for example, that you could have chosen $10$ vectors that are all the same for $S$. In which case you could pick 5 identical ones for $S_1$ and 5 identical ones for $S_2$ which clearly would have the same sum.

Comment: So that's the same as allowing coefficients bigger than 1, only you insist that altogether the coefficients don't add up to more than 10.

Comment: @GerryMyerson You would never choose the same vector twice of course.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I removed the word multi as it wasn't helpful.  Also, are you sure about $18$? Can you write out what the vectors would be?

Comment: @marshall, why not?

Comment: I retract the 18 vectors suggestion. I do think you can do better than 10, but I don't know how much better. E.g., if the problem were for length 3, you could use the 4 vectors 110, 101, 011, 100.

Comment: If $k$ is the answer, we know that $2^k \le k^{10}$ and hence $k \le 58$. But this is probably an asymptotically wrong estimate.

Comment: @user21820 Can you explain where you get this inequality from?  I am pretty sure you can get $k=11$ but anything like as big as you suggest seems very surprising.

Comment: @Lembik: It's just a loose upper bound; there are $2^k$ possible subsets which must have distinct sums with each element in the range $[0..k]$, so technically it should be $2^k \le (k+1)^{10}$, which gives $k \le 59$. But as I said earlier, it's probably very far from the actual value.

Comment: @user21820 There might be a misunderstanding. Each element is a vector of length $10$. The sums are just elementwise addition of vectors. The sum of two vectors is another vector.

Comment: @felix: Exactly. Read my comment again. Each subset has a sum which is a vector with $10$ elements, each of which must be in the range $[0..k]$.

Comment: @user21820 Ah yes! Thanks :)

Comment: When you say "a vector of length 10" that typically means a vector whose norm is 10, for example $\langle 6,8\rangle$. Might I suggest you change the wording to "a 10-tuple" or "a vector from $\mathbb{R}^{10}$" or something along these lines?

Comment: @alex.jordan Good point. Hopefully it is improved now.

Comment: If we view the subset sums in the mechanism of the upper bound by @user21820 as random elements of $[0,k]^{10}$, then  the [Birthday paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) kicks in: if you draw elements (with replacement) from a set of $N$ objects, then you expect reappearances after $O(\sqrt N)$ draws. This doesn't prove anything, but suggests that random search techniques will balk approximately when $2^k$ exceeds $(k+1)^5$. This happens, when $k\ge23$. That is probably closer to the mark than the $59$, but I don't see a way of turning this heuristic into an upper bound.

Comment: Have a look at my graph-theoretic model; I think we can cooperative push the lower bound with a little effort.

Comment: One could also replace $10$ by $n$, try to solve the problem exactly for smaller $n$, then see if there's a pattern.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: about suggestion of 18 vectors : i found 18 sum-free vectors :)

Comment: So I was right, but for utterly wrong reasons.

Comment: $n \mapsto \lfloor \frac{1}{2} (n+1) log_2(n+1) \rfloor$ fits the sequence $(1,2,4,5,7,9,12,...)$ exactly and has the correct asymptotic bound. It's almost surely wrong, but so very nice! It predicts that the correct answer for this should be 19.

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE**:

My best result (for vectors with $10$ elements) is $18$.

(But **Brendan McKay** obtained set of **19** vectors: see cited above [http://mathoverflow.net](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/157634/number-of-vectors-so-that-no-two-subset-sums-are-equal) link).

Example of $18$ sum-free binary vectors:

$\qquad(0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1)$,
$\qquad(0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1)$,
$\qquad(0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1)$,
$\qquad(0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0)$,
$\qquad(0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0)$,
$\qquad(0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0)$,
$\qquad(0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0)$,
$\qquad(0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1)$,
$\qquad(0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1)$,
$\qquad(0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1)$,
$\qquad(1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1)$,
$\qquad(1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1)$,
$\qquad(1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1)$,
$\qquad(1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1)$,
$\qquad(1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1)$,
$\qquad(1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1)$,
$\qquad(1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0)$,
$\qquad(1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0)$.

Example of $17$ sum-free binary vectors:

$\qquad(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1)$,
$\qquad(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1)$,
$\qquad(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0)$,
$\qquad(0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1)$,
$\qquad(0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1)$,
$\qquad(0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1)$,
$\qquad(0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0)$,
$\qquad(0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0)$,
$\qquad(1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0)$,
$\qquad(1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1)$,
$\qquad(1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0)$,
$\qquad(1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)$,
$\qquad(1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1)$,
$\qquad(1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0)$,
$\qquad(1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0)$,
$\qquad(1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0)$,
$\qquad(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1)$.

And example of $11$ sum-free binary vectors (just for curious):

$\qquad(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)$,
$\qquad(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)$,
$\qquad(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)$,
$\qquad(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)$,
$\qquad(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0)$,
$\qquad(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)$,
$\qquad(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0)$,
$\qquad(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0)$,
$\qquad(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0)$,
$\qquad(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1)$,
$\qquad(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1)$.

---

For $3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10$-dimensional vectors my best results are $4,5,7,9,12,14,16,18$ accordingly.

Comment: How did you do this? There are $2^{170}$ matrices of size $10$ by $17$ so I can't imagine you tried them all!

Comment: @felix If you were to try examining all such matrices, you would not need to look at as many as $2^{170}$. Rows and columns can be permuted giving any one such matrix possibly as many as $10!\cdot17!$ representations. That still leaves over $10^{30}$ matrices to check, but that's a lot less than $2^{170}\approx10^{51}$. If exhaustive searching is to be used, a clever search algorithm might take advantage of this.

Comment: @alex.jordan True. It's still far too many however and even checking one is laborious.  Oleg567 must have found a smart way to do this.

Comment: These results are obtained (I assume) by generating random sets of vectors incrementally.  That is, generate a random binary vector, then add it to the list if it doesn't create a duplicate sum; stop after failing a certain number of times.  When I carry out this procedure, I also obtain maximum sizes of $7,9,11,13,15,17$ for $n=5-10$.

Comment: @mjqxxxx Thank you that is interesting. I suppose this counts the values of $k$ where subset-distinct answers are very common.

Comment: @mjqxxxx, you are right: just random sets of vectors, etc. This procedure needs only $\approx$ a few millions of tries.

Comment: Did you restart from an empty set of vectors each time, or did you backtrack and try a few possible vectors at each branch? If the latter, then I suspect the optimal should be quite close, even though such problems tend to have rare optimal solutions and so we're probably unlikely to get any of them through randomized algorithms.

Comment: @user21820: First time I generated random 17-tuples of vectors. It was time expensive. After that, I generated (for example) random 15-tuples first; then expand with 1 vector (brute force, 1023 variants) to get possible 16-tuples; then expand with 1 vector to get possible 17-tuples.   At all, there are many "good" 15-tuples among randoms: $\approx$ 1 "good" per 24 tested.

Comment: Can someone provide fast pseudocode for checking the sum-free property of a set of vectors?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, are you familiar with C++? If so, then I can provide.

Comment: @Oleg567: actually I am a Maxima (LISP) programmer, but I am quite fluent in C, too; I think it is pretty much the same for these tasks, am I right?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: I edited my post. Here you can find some "pseudocode" of checking sum-free property.

Comment: @Oleg567: thanks so much.

Comment: @felix, I get $\Large\bf 18$ sum-free binary vectors!!! (see update).

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, "pseudocode" of checking I've posted is not so fast, but easy. There exist faster method, using quickSort or heapSort. In 2 words, you generate array of sums. Then quick-sort it. Then search equal elements a[i], a[i+1].

Comment: @Oleg567: Nice! So I think what I said is true, that optimal solutions are very sparse and isolated. I suppose it's like the optimal Rubik's cube algorithm...

Comment: @felix, my result $18$ is not top-result. Brendan McKay obtained set of $\Large\bf{19}$ vectors. Please remove me from current records. Set please Brendan McKay and his $19$ instead. (on this website and on mathoverflow too).

Answer (score 5):

An SSD-sequence is a sequence of positive integer numbers in which distinct subsets have distinct sums. If we fill our vectors with the binary representations of the elements of such a sequence, we clearly end with a sum-disjoint set of vectors. For istance, taking the SSD-sequence $3,5,6,7$ we have that $011,101,110,111$ are four sum-disjoint vectors in $\{0,1\}^3$.
Erdos conjectured that 
$$M_n = \min\{\max(S)\;|\; S \mbox{ is a SSD sequence of length } n\}$$
satisfies $M_n \geq c\cdot 2^n$ for some constant $c$, and the problem is still open. On the other hand, it is easy to see that $M_n\leq\frac{1}{2}2^n$ by simply taking powers of two (or the identity matrix in our initial problem).
[Bohman](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1996-124-12/S0002-9939-96-03653-2/S0002-9939-96-03653-2.pdf) proved in 1996 that the $k$ elements $s_i=a_k-a_{k-i}$ are an SSD-set, where $1\leq i\leq k$ and $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is the [Conway-Guy sequence](http://oeis.org/A005318)
$$ 0, 1, 2, 4, 7, 13, 24, 44, 84, 161, 309, 594, 1164, 2284, 4484, 8807, 17305, 34301, 68008, 134852, 267420, 530356, 1051905, 2095003, 4172701, 8311101, 16554194, 32973536, 65679652, 130828948, 261127540, 521203175, 1040311347, 2076449993, \ldots$$
defined by $a_0=0,a_1=1$ and
$$ a_{n+1} = 2a_n - a_{n-\lfloor\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{2n}\rfloor}. $$
This gave the bound $M_n\leq 2^{n-2}$ for $n\geq 20$, for istance. Taking $k=11$ we get the eleven-elements SSD set:
$$\{594,593,592,590,587,581,570,550,510,433,285\}$$
and by taking binary representations we have eleven sum-disjoint vectors in $\{0,1\}^{10}$ - in general, $n+2$ sum-disjoint vectors in $\{0,1\}^n$ for any $n\geq 20$ - not so many, but still better than the trivial bound.

We are clearly wasting a lot of information, since, for istance, $\{3,4,5,6,8\}$ is not an SSD-set (due to $5+6=8+3$), but the binary representations of $\{3,4,5,6,8\}$ give a five-elements sum-disjoint set of vectors in $\{0,1\}^4$.

Since there are $4$ sum-disjoint vectors in $\{0,1\}^3$, a clever tensor-trick gives that there are at least $\left\lfloor\frac{4n}{3}\right\rfloor$ sum-disjoint vectors in $\{0,1\}^n$. In the case $n=10$, these thirteen vectors are:
$$\begin{array}{*10{c}}
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0\\
0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0\\
0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0\\
0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0\\
0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0\\
0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0\\
0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0\\
0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0\\
0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0\\
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0\\
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1\\
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0\\
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1 \end{array}.$$
For the same reason, since there are $7$ sum-disjoint vectors in $\{0,1\}^5$, 
there are at least $14$ sum-disjoint vectors in $\{0,1\}^{10}$ and at least $\left\lfloor\frac{7n}{5}\right\rfloor$ sum-disjoint vectors in $\{0,1\}^n$.

Monte-Carlo computations below seem to suggest that there are at least $2n-3$ sum-disjoint vectors in $\{0,1\}^n$ for any $n\geq 4$. In order to fix notation, let $I_n$ be the maximum number of sum-disjoint vectors in $\{0,1\}^n$. If we manage to prove $$I_{n+1}\geq I_n+2,\tag{1}$$
we prove the $2n-3$-bound.

A simple way to achieve $(1)$ would be to take the vectors giving $I_n$, augment them with a zero in the first coordinate, then take the two additional vectors $(1,0,0,\ldots)$ and $(1,1,1,\ldots)$. Unluckyly, this naive construction does not work since $(1,1,1,1)=(1,0,0,0)+(0,1,0,0)+(0,0,1,1)$, but may be we can fix it.

There is also a graph-theoretic interpretation that may be useful. Consider a bipartite undirected graph $G$ with $m$ red nodes and $n$ ($10$ in the original problem) blue nodes (emitters), where distinct blue nodes have distinct neighbourhoods and there are only edges between a blue node and a red node. Every emitter can give a $+1$,$0$ or $-1$ weight to the elements of the set of its outcoming edges; the weight of a blue vertex is the sum of the weigths of its incoming edges. **Sum-free property**: if for every non-trivial weigth-assignment there exists a blue vertex with non-zero weight, we get $m$ sum-disjoint elements in $\{0,1\}^n$. For istance, the following "sum-free" graph:

[image: A sum-free graph]

gives $I_3\geq 4$ through the set of sum-free vectors $110,101,110,001$ corresponding to the neighbourhoods of the red nodes. The graph corresponding to the SSD-set $011,101,110,111$ is even nicer:

[image: Another sum-free graph]

In the [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1005.0155) paper Lev shows, through the probabilistic method,
$$ I_n \geq \frac{1}{\log_2 9}\cdot(1+o(1))\cdot n\log_2(n), $$
and I think it is worth to reproduce its arguments in the specific $n=10$ case. Let $S=\{-1,0,1\}^{17}$. For any $s\in S$, let $m^+$ be the number of positive coordinates of $s$ and $m^-$ the number of negative coordinates of $s$. For a random chosen vector $d\in\{0,1\}^{17}$ the probability of being orthogonal to $s$ is equal to:

$$ \frac{1}{2^{m^+ + m^-}}\sum_{j=0}^{\min(m^-,m^+)}\binom{m^+}{j}\binom{m^-}{j}=\frac{1}{2^{m^+ + m^-}}\binom{m^+ + m^-}{m^+},$$

hence the probability for $10$ randomly chosen vectors to be simultaneously orthogonal to $s$ is very small. Since the number of elements of $S$ of a given $(m^-,m^+)$-type is just $\binom{17}{m^+ + m^-}\binom{m^+ + m^-}{m^+}$, in order to prove $I_{10}\geq 17$ it is sufficient to show that:

$$\sum_{1\leq m^+ + m^- \leq 17}\binom{17}{m^+ + m^-}\binom{m^+ + m^-}{m^+}\left(\frac{1}{2^{m^+ + m^-}}\binom{m^+ + m^-}{m^+}\right)^{10} <1,$$

that is true by direct computation. Moreover, I am now noticing that through a probabilistic argument (the Hoeffding bound) Seva on MO pushed the upper bound down to $30$.

Comment: The wheel-graph is great!

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something, the claim is that knowing the degree of each blue vertex lets you uniquely identify the red nodes that are in a subgraph?  This isn't true for the wheel graph shown.  Every "pac-man" path around the outside that dips into the center once gives the same degrees to all the blue vertices, no matter where it dips in.

Comment: The cycle $(2,3,4,10)$, for instance, with alternating positive and negative signs, gives zero weight to all blue vertices.

Comment: @mjqxxx: yes, you're right, the wheel graph depicted is not sum-free. We need graphs without cycles of even length (then we place the "emitters" in the midpoint of every edge), I bet a lot is known about this topic.

Comment: I think we can fix the wheel-graph issue by connecting the midpoint of the $4-5$ edge with the opposite vertex $9$ and so on, am I right?

Comment: Nope, still no good.  The sum of $\{9,1,10\}$ and $\{1,2\}$ is the same as the sum of $\{1,2,10\}$ and $\{9,1\}$.

Comment: (I was commenting on the modified graph in the figure, not the one you just described in the comments.)

Comment: Uhm, wait, if you switch on the emitters on the $9-10$,$10-1$,$1-2$ and $9-1$ edges then vertex $8$ cannot have weigth zero. If I'm not wrong, once you switch on an emitter then you have to switch on all the emitters on the boundary, but the boundary is a $4k+2$-cycle, so some vertex must have a non-zero weight.

Comment: I'm referring to the red nodes you've drawn on the $10-1$ ($=\{9,1,10\}$), $10-2$ ($=\{1,2,10\}$), $9-1$ and $1-2$ edges.  These four can be turned on to give all vertices zero weight, since $+\{9,1,10\}-\{9,1\}=+\{1,2,10\}-\{1,2\}$.

Comment: Ok, let's see if the new one works.

Comment: Label the blue nodes 1 through 10 in the following manner:

$$
\begin{matrix}
&1&&&&4 \\
2&&3&&5&&6 \\
& \\
&&7&&8 \\
&&&9 \\
& \\
&&&10
\end{matrix}
$$

Then there is a cycle (2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10) of even length, and as above, alternating signs here will zero out all weights (sorry!)

Comment: @jpvee: That's quite frustrating but I still believe we are on the right track. Is someone willing to give me a hand in (suitable-) graphs generation? I wonder if adding some edge in the depicted graph solves all the issues. Maybe "breaking" the $4k$-cycles by adding an edge between two vertices of the cycle...

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Nope, won't work either (yellow is +1, green is -1):

![18 Vectors](http://i57.tinypic.com/w0hngz.png)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: I admire the pretty pictures you draw, but the current one (EME9A.png) isn't working either: The topmost red node can be zeroed out by the ones connecting 1 and 4 resp. 2 and 5.

Comment: @jpvee: thanks. I will keep trying for a while :)

Comment: The last graph does not work either, since we can take the $1-4-5-2$ path with alternating charges, then the $6-10-8-5$ path with alternating charges chosen in such a way that the charge on $7$ is zero :/

Comment: Here in $\{0,1\}^9$ example there are equal sums: 'cause of some symmetry: $$110110110+101101101+011011011$$ $$=111111000+111000111+000111111$$ $$=222222222.$$

Comment: Your most recent lower bound conjecture is not right. See the mathoverflow question.

Comment: @marshall: Could you post the link to the MO question?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio The OP put the link in this question.

Comment: The asymptotic constant from paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/1005.0155 should in fact be $2$ . See  http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~colt2009/papers/004.pdf .

Answer (score 4):

Given a particular subset $S'\subset S$, you can think of each position in the sum as a measurement: the $i$-th measurement tells you how many elements of $S'$ have a $1$ in the $i$-th position.  Equivalently, the $i$-th measurement gives you the size of $S'\cap A_i$, where $A_i=\{x\in S \;|\; \pi_i(x)=1\}$.  How large can $S$ be if you can identify an arbitrary subset using $n$ such measurements?  Well, if $|S|=k$, then each measurement can have $k+1$ different outcomes, and so the most information it can give you is $\log_2(k+1)$ bits.  Since you need to distinguish between $2^k$ subsets, you need to obtain $k$ bits of information in total, so
$$
n \log_2(k+1) \ge k,
$$
or
$$
\frac{k}{\log_2(k+1)} \le n.
$$
For $n=10$, for instance, this implies $|S| \le 59$.

Comment: I think  @user21820 got the same bound in the comments by a direct counting argument.

Comment: Yes, the counting argument and the information argument are equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

A slight improvement to the upper bound showing that the answer is $\le 47$. Assume contrariwise that a set $S$ of $48$ such vectors would exist. The set $S$ has
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{24}{48\choose k}=156\,861\,290\,196\,877
$$
subsets of at most $24$ elements. The sum vectors of those subsets belong to the set $\{0,1,\ldots,24\}^{10}$ that has $25^{10}=95\,367\,431\,640\,625$ elements. Therefore a collision is inevitable by the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: We can, of course, try and tune this up further by using the maximum size of a subset as a parameter. I don't think that we get close to the true value this way though (see my comment under the OP for a heuristic).

Comment: While I can see that without loss of generality, we can assume that **one** of the subsets $S_1$ and $S_2$ has cardinality $\le n/2$, I fail to understand why this should be the case for **both** of them.

Comment: @jpvee: The idea here is that if we get a repeated sum vector with both subsets small, then we have already shown that the set $S$ didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification; I understand your argument now.

Comment: Using Jyrki's argument, the upper bound can still be slightly improved to $\le 45$, since $$\sum_{k=1}^{17} {46\choose k} = 3\,652\,326\,252\,869 > 3\,570\,467\,226\,624 = (17+1)^{10}.$$

Comment: Nice, @jpvee! ${}$